# cudaGetDeviceCount returns 0

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-12.04, nvidia

I am running the following code. However, I am getting output as
Got error with code 38
test = 0
deviceCount= 0
Got error with code 38
test2 = 0
I have an NVIDIA GTX 690 graphics card on Ubuntu. Does that mean the driver is not activated?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
__device__ __constant__ float* data;

template<class T> void allocOnly(T* deviceDest, size_t numElem)
{
    cudaError_t errCode = cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceDest, numElem*sizeof(T));
    if(errCode != cudaSuccess) 
        cout << "Got error with code " << errCode << endl;
}

int main()
{
    float* test(0);
    allocOnly<float>(test,10);
    cout << "test = " << test << endl;
    int deviceCount = 0;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
    cout << "deviceCount= " << deviceCount << endl;

    float* test2(0);    
    cudaError_t errCode = cudaMalloc((void**)&test2, 10*sizeof(float));
    if(errCode != cudaSuccess) 
        cout << "Got error with code " << errCode << endl;
    cout << "test2 = " << test2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but if you are running ubuntu on a recent laptop you may need Bumblebee because of Nvidia Optimus, in order to install drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a problem with your system setup.  Try running `nvidia-smi -a` from a terminal and see what it reports.

You should be doing [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on the call to `cudaGetDeviceCount` (and all cuda API calls and kernel calls).  The [error returned from that API call](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gd3f924ba23b94793b0c93b2addba0741) would also be instructive.

It would also make sense to me to perform the call to `cudaGetDeviceCount` *before* any other cuda API calls (such as the call to `cudaMalloc` in `allocOnly`).

Comment: Thanks Robert I got the error jumioadmin@cudaGPU:~/cuda-convnet$ nvidia-smi -a
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidiactl (No such file or directory).
Nvidia-smi has failed because it couldn't communicate with NVIDIA driver. Make sure that latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
I have the .run files from the NVIDIA website. What else do I need to do to get it to run each time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You may need to instantiate the necessary files by running something like `nvidia-smi` as a root user.  Or maybe you just need to install the driver.  Or maybe you are running into a conflict with a nouveau driver.  I'm not really able to diagnose your system based on this information.  Also, helping you get your system set up properly is off-topic for SO.  You might want to read the linux [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html) as some of these topics are covered there.

Comment: The error returned from `cudaGetDeviceCount` would not be "instructive". That call is defined to always return `cudaSuccess`: See [the manual](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g665468e8cb33be42434f11bee2684ec9.html)

Comment: @ChrisKitching The manual you linked is quite old and is hosted by CMU, not NVIDIA.  The current NVIDIA manual page is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g18808e54893cfcaafefeab31a73cc55f) and it gives at least 2 situations where the "defined" return code may be different than `cudaSuccess`: 1. Note that this function may also return error codes from previous, asynchronous launches. 2. If no driver can be loaded to determine if any such devices exist then `cudaGetDeviceCount()` will return `cudaErrorInsufficientDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command.. It should solve the problem..

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus
```